# How can I load a function when loading a highchart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

HighCharts provides this example for async server loading:

http://jsfiddle.net/q40Lz13c/

JS:

```
$(function () {
/**
 * Load new data depending on the selected min and max
 */
function afterSetExtremes(e) {

    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();

    chart.showLoading('Loading data from server...');
    $.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/from-sql.php?start=' + Math.round(e.min) +
            '&end=' + Math.round(e.max) + '&callback=?', function (data) {

        chart.series[0].setData(data);
        chart.hideLoading();
    });
}

// See source code from the JSONP handler at https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/samples/data/from-sql.php
$.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/from-sql.php?callback=?', function (data) {

    // Add a null value for the end date
    data = [].concat(data, [[Date.UTC(2011, 9, 14, 19, 59), null, null, null, null]]);

    // create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
        chart : {
            type: 'candlestick',
            zoomType: 'x'
        },

        navigator : {
            adaptToUpdatedData: false,
            series : {
                data : data
            }
        },

        scrollbar: {
            liveRedraw: false
        },

        title: {
            text: 'AAPL history by the minute from 1998 to 2011'
        },

        subtitle: {
            text: 'Displaying 1.7 million data points in Highcharts Stock by async server loading'
        },

        rangeSelector : {
            buttons: [{
                type: 'hour',
                count: 1,
                text: '1h'
            }, {
                type: 'day',
                count: 1,
                text: '1d'
            }, {
                type: 'month',
                count: 1,
                text: '1m'
            }, {
                type: 'year',
                count: 1,
                text: '1y'
            }, {
                type: 'all',
                text: 'All'
            }],
            inputEnabled: false, // it supports only days
            selected : 4 // all
        },

        xAxis : {
            events : {
                afterSetExtremes : afterSetExtremes
            },
            minRange: 3600 * 1000 // one hour
        },

        yAxis: {
            floor: 0
        },

        series : [{
            data : data,
            dataGrouping: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

But function  afterSetExtremes(e) only loads when the chart is zoomed. How can I run it while loading my chart inittialy?

Comment: How Highcharts can provide `min` and `max` when there is no data on the chart? Anyway, I would try something like this: `chart.events.load = function () { afterSetExtremes({ min: 0, max: +new Date()}); };`

Comment: As suggested by @PawełFus chart{ events: {load: function(){ // put your function here }}}

Answer (score 0):

You can add a third Parameter to the Chart constructor which is a callback function that is executed after the Chart was constructed:

```
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
        [... options ...]
    }, function(chart) {

      chart.showLoading('Loading data from server...');

      $.getJSON('https://yoururl.com&callback=?', function (data) {
          chart.series[0].setData(data);
          chart.hideLoading();
      });
});
```

see http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Highcharts.Chart

Comment: This won't work - you will receive errors in console like `can not read property "min" of undefined`. That is `e.min` and `e.max` will be undefined (missing `e` variable).